# Generic function for sorting a nested array of objects

Tags: typescript

I want to sort a nested array using a generic function. It should be sorted by the values of the items from the nested array.

#### My array:

```
type Person = {
    id: number,
    name: string,
    childs: Child[]
}


type Child = {
    id: number,
    name: string,
}

const persons : Person[] = [
    {
        id: 1, name: 'Person 1', 
        childs:[
            {id: 1, name: 'Child 1'},
            {id: 2, name: 'Child 2'}
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 2, name: 'Person 2', 
        childs:[
            {id: 1, name: 'Child 1'},
        ]
    },
        {
        id: 3, name: 'Person 3', 
        childs:[
            {id: 1, name: 'Child 1'},
            {id: 2, name: 'Child 2'}
            {id: 3, name: 'Child 3'}
        ]
    },  
];
```

As a result, I want to call my sort function like this:

```
sortNestedArrays(persons, 'childs', 'name');
```

That means: Sort the nested array 'childs' by the property 'name'.

#### My approach

I've been struggling with the correct syntax for this function for hours now.

```
type ArrayElement<ArrayType extends readonly unknown[]> = 
  ArrayType extends readonly (infer ElementType)[] ? ElementType : never;

type KeysMatching<T, V> = {[K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends V ? K : never}[keyof T];

/**
 * @param array Main array.
 * @param keyOfSubArray Key of the elements in 'array' that leads to the value of the nested array.
 * @param propertyName Key by which the nested array is sorted.
 */
function sortNestedArrays<A, K extends KeysMatching<A, unknown[]>>(array: A[], keyOfSubArray: K, propertyName: ???){
    array.forEach((member) => {
        const nestedArray = member[keyOfSubArray];
        nestedArray.forEach((nestedMember) => {

        });
    });
}
```

This is my result so far. With `KeysMatching` I could achieve that the argument `keyOfSubArray` accepts only keys that are of type array, so that the nested array can be accessed safely.

However, Typescript does not understand the following lines. Since `keyOfSubArray` can only be a key that points to an array, it follows that `member[keyOfSubArray` must also be an array. However, the compiler throws the following error message:
**Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'A[K]'.**

```
const nestedArray = member[keyOfSubArray];
nestedArray.forEach((nestedMember) => {

});
```

#### My questions

1st) Why doesn't the compiler recognize that `member[keyOfSubArray]` **must** be an array and how can I solve this problem?

2nd) In the next step, I need to specify the argument `propertyName` which must be a key of the items in the subarray (`keyof Child`). How can I specify this correctly as generic in the function?

#### Playground

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgziA2CmB0w4EMBOAKAlAbgFC4HoCACAWnIsquptrvvsJIBUBNABQFEBlJshgYKFD8AFwCeAB1jF2sVFDDEAvMQDeuYluIBLACYAuYmACuAWwBG8gDSbtYZGdhGIo1DrABzW9uLAAFjrQehBGAMKBwQDaALq4AL74uBLSxBFBeirqdlr6RqaWNjnGjs7Eru5etol8wnX19XwA8hYAVrDAorUNPb00%20KCQosTSCuAQxEZyY2CxWVHFGr6%20ecQAjNYlTkYA5NOK6zubxb4BGaELy1fqqxtbZTvpwYfxPte%20aqsATJsO28SPSKZL47RLvOK%20V6LE7ab6-Uq7fbgYgg47vM7BC4wq6fQzreH-QEZF5vK4Q7RQ95La6rADMBIeSKUtKOxGxfiBWPeH1uDN2T0ya1BpO5uKMdz%20DwFKNB7J5eIlCIB0pZYOu5K0ry0uBieG6fQNvT4ADETGBOjpwPrDTbhGIpDIAIKoVDIcScOBOMCiAA8ztd4mYDuIsAAHqJYGAQsRULBkHpwNBxMQzQBrMAgADusxiAD4snZ-W6g6kwxGoxNY-HE8n0B4AGbyYge2Be0Ql2CYOYAfmbnsj7eD%20VgADd5HqUjIANKwcQQACyyFEZy8PuYmwAavnVGoolPdEpU7OQPXiMwYqRu0ZmHuYiHw5HoxviL398Ox6h4lEj%20IT2fdfgBAAFRAZoQHEAAApIaCOMQaABsQi4eHBLpuvAYGQdBrpmMQP5NPW3AmBYRbJjOyZ-qI-gyLA-behMyE7PBbo7MQlFLsQKDRqIICsVRxAjsg0AmDIFF8WAsCuLAmRMeI6HEOBUEwThkioCAowSAAcqUxBkcQFjJpmgQBLxMjiZJ0mocmOgTFAqARnoclAQQuD1maFrIrZogaRJ9kkRAfqbPuZaPhMZELkuK6eAFKZgOmWY5rmuboDJRiOrEmx4QRREkUYU6bCpanyJpSrdqVmDUloMnwPWICoJwyABOg6BOIUqCYCo%20YVcsgyuMYPlSSRWQtVYqDfrO%20GEcRlkAe8Zm%20ZZ1W1fVjXoHNUnzq2I3tconX4O88Q4MUB14DUSSed55l%20egoyKBAmw7BiISsjsko7DgQA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your first question: *"Why doesn't the compiler recognize that `member[keyOfSubArray]` must be an array?"*. Because it has no reason to assume so. You specified that the `array` parameter passed to the function is of type `A`. You did not further constrain this generic type to be of any particular shape, so it could be anything.

You should constrain `A` with additional information.

```
function sortNestedArrays<
  A extends Record<K, unknown[]>, 
  K extends KeysMatching<A, unknown[]>
>(array: A[], keyOfSubArray: K, propertyName: ???){}
```

Now the compiler knows that `A` must have a property `K` which has an array type.

---

The second problem is of similar nature. You should tell the compiler that the type of the array inside `A` is also important by using another generic type `P`.

```
function sortNestedArrays<
  A extends Record<K, P[]>,
  K extends KeysMatching<A, unknown[]>,
  P
>(array: A[], keyOfSubArray: K, propertyName: keyof P){}
```

We will use `P` as the type of the elements inside the array in `A` and also for the `propertyName` parameter.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=72&ssc=2&pln=61&pc=1#code/MYewdgziA2CmB0w4EMBOAKAlAbgFC4HoCACAWnIsquptrvvsJIBUBNABQFEBlJshgYKFD8AFwCeAB1jF2sVFDDEAvMQDeuYluIBLACYAuYmACuAWwBG8gDSbtYZGdhGIo1DrABzW9uLAAFjrQehBGAMKBwQDaALq4AL74uBLSxBFBeirqdlr6RqaWNjnGjs7Eru5etol8wnX19XwA8hYAVrDAorUNPb00%20KCQosTSCuAQxEZyY2CxWVHFGr6%20ecQAjNYlTkYA5NOK6zubxb4BGaELy1fqqxtbZTvpwYfxPte%20aqsATJsO28SPSKZL47RLvOK%20V6LE7ab6-Uq7fbgYgg47vM7BC4wq6fQzreH-QEZF5vK4Q7RQ95La6rADMBIeSKUtKOxGxfiBWPeH1uDN2T0ya1BpO5uKMdz%20DwFKOF7J5eIlCIB0pZYOu5K0ry0uBieG6fQNvT4ADETGBOjpwPrDTbhGIpDIAIKoVDIcScOBOMCiAA8ztd4mYDuIsAAHqJYGAQsRULBkHpwNBxMQzQBrMAgADusxiAD4snZ-W6g6kwxGoxNY-HE8n0B4AGbyYge2Be0Ql2CYOYAfmbnsj7eD%20VgADd5HqUjIANKwcQQACyyFEZy8PuYmwAavnVGoolPdEpU7OQPXiMwYqRu0ZmHuYiHw5HoxviL398Ox6h4lEj%20IT2fdfgBAAFRAZoQHEAAApIaCOMQaABsQi4eHBLpuvAYGQdBrpmMQP5NPW3AmBYRbJjOyZ-qI-gyLA-behMyE7PBbo7MQlFLsQKDRqIICsVRxAjsg0AmDIFF8WAsCuLAmRMeI6HEOBUEwThkioCAowSAAcqUxBkcQFjJpmgQBLxMjiZJ0mocmOgTFAqARnoclAQQuD1maFrIrZogaRJ9kkRAPqFve5bRgASh0ICoHoPpTps7CxLmbz7mWj4TGRC5Liunh%20psaYZtm8VvOwuC5ugMlGI6sSbHhBFESRRgxSMqnqeIWn-D%20f7sJg1JaDJ8D1hFnDIAE6DoE4hSoJgKj5t1yyDK4xg%20VJJFZGNVioN%20s74YRxGWQB7xmb5ll9QNQ3%20CNB1SfOrZrZNyjTfg7zxDgxRPXgNRJJ53nmX56CjIoECbDsGIhKyOz6DsOBAA)

---

We can make it slightly shorter:

```
function sortNestedArrays<
  A extends Record<K, unknown[]>,
  K extends KeysMatching<A, unknown[]>
>(array: A[], keyOfSubArray: K, propertyName: keyof A[K][number]){
    array.forEach((member) => {
        const nestedArray = member[keyOfSubArray];
        nestedArray.forEach((nestedMember) => {

        });
    });
}
```

This will also fix the auto-completion issue.

Comment: First of all, thank you for the help. One question about this: why does the compiler not suggest an autocomplete for the argument ````propertyName````?

Comment: @michaelT I noticed this too. I guess these relations are a bit too complicated for the auto suggestion to understand. This field will be validated and will show an error when given a wrong value though. But I can't give you a definitive answer to this :/

Comment: I was also wondering about this. But your solution is much more clear and easier to understand than my approach. Thank you!

Comment: @TobiasS. can't `K` also be specified to be `extends KeysMatching<A, P[]>`?

Comment: @Dean actually we can get rid of the generic type `P` alltogether and also fix the autocompletion. See my edit

Comment: yeah makes sense. a little bit less explicit than my answer with the autocompletion fix, but on the other hand cleaner. can go either way i presume. nice!

Answer (score 2):

To build on Tobias' answer:

```
type ExtractFromArray<T extends any[]> = T extends (infer Type)[] ? Type : never;

/**
 * @param array Main array.
 * @param keyOfSubArray Key of the elements in 'array' that leads to the value of the nested array.
 * @param propertyName Key by which the nested array is sorted.
 */
function sortNestedArrays<
  A extends Record<K, C[]>,
  K extends KeysMatching<A, C[]>,
  C = ExtractFromArray<A[K]>,
>(array: A[], keyOfSubArray: K, propertyName: keyof C){}

sortNestedArrays(persons, "childs", "id")
```

In this scenario you will have key suggestions for your last parameter because we explicitly specify that it must be a key of the combination of `A[K]` (your previous params) which is `Child[]` and then using the `ExtractFromArray` type to get the keys of `Child` and not `Child[]`.

Test it in the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAChBOBnA9gOygXigbwFBQKgEsATALilQFcBbAIwQBp9DUBDGiCxYeI1AObNCUAMYALIgBsSiCgGFJMgNoBdXAF9c20JCiLpJTDhYFSFavSanKHLlB59BzLblFoeUSEg9QKcH1Q1Y2UbPBERcygARkZbTgoAcgCUdGjEuJsRCUM5UIiCnCjY+PtEgxkYxI1hQpFsKIAmOPYEqHKlI0bqrMJ1ERqw3rNyKGbSpJS0MYyoYbFOvPn64pa7JIqjdMG6-sIdwvDCqIBmNbbkhFSoE9n5nJklupXRktayzaqD56LR8feNp0Zt9ng1RmcJu1PrctLsbDUCLhVABuHTgaAAQXg8DYIAAolIIJxUMAADxYnEgAAq6KgEAAHsAIKhZFB4BA2CQ0FIQFAqKgANaoZAAdyCqgAfMYWBTcTS9AymSzEGyOVzUDyoAAKfgAMwQUAJROZwHlEAAlMEAPyGwnE020iwQABuCFRuF00AA0hAQIgALJsYA5QSkqlxABqUqw2GUXuI6AFvuQuqgVNUAForRQqXHVHTGczWRGoDb407XfANMokyAU2mUWi9HjGTjRMAAGLwZA0WUgMMFpWstioEBqaNpwdFlU61D6+Bp9GW-M2s1+Sgut3aAD0ACpd-hd1AAAJgNg4mhQc+UqCB-hX7G4gB0h5PZ4vUFrAHldQBlKh0H2UA+ry9bAOI0AQHaJoqveiTXriiRQOBQZQISnIqsAyDIRBUDOmwUhUNAYG4agEA8BARgISAL5QEep7nhwXjdt4oAAHJ2MBvpQHQvIipIEg4dAZEUVRj68kQKooPATIkLRu7brgur8u2RDTNJwBseRsl9ogpIylOypQAAShA7jwCQpJenE8jjrU8aKtOXF+oGwaSKGGI2XZLDyMYLa8Gw7Zdj2fbknmErMBKWrURQGJqHE35-gBfYUNZzHIKxIAcW0tb1vI5pHAQ1FPrqyDwHigXiFqJrwLyGBSjVY6Jf+gHiaoJVlRVEhag8Rj1QshjKGALEIOxdiqOa5qaNouAaVpom6Vq3ipIgcQAES9Yga3raQa3mkAA).

Comment: There's a problem with your solution. When I want to access the ````propertyName```` property with the ````nestedMember```` (typeof Child), the compiler throws the error: **Type 'keyof ExtractFromArray<A[K]>' cannot be used to index type 'C'.** Playground: tsplay.dev/m3P9LW

Comment: you are right, should be fixed now. answer and playground updated